# Issues with Async/await. Not running next line

Tags: node.js, async-await

working with some heavily asynchronous code, and I'm not sure why some code is not running. I'm not really getting errors from the VS code debugger on why.

I have a function that reads in a CSV file, then queries a SQL database.

```
const db = require('./db');
const csv = require('csvtojson');
const path = require('path');

const remapGroups = async () => {
    try{
        let fileName = path.join(__dirname, 'fnvgroups.csv');
        let data = await csv().fromFile(fileName);
        let idMap = []
        let pool = await db.getPoolConnection();
        data.forEach( async (x) => {
            let id = `FNV-${x.External_ID}`;
            let query = `select distinct finalId from ns_union..tblUnion where sourceId='${id}'`;
            let result = await db.queryUnion(pool, query);
            idMap.push({original: id, final: result});
        });
        console.dir(idMap);
    }catch(err) {
        console.error(err);
    }
}
```

the pertinent parts are from the `db.js` file are the `getPoolConnection` function:

```
const mssql = require('mssql');
const getPoolConnection = async ( srvaddress = server) => {
  try {
    let pool = await mssql.connect({
      user: username,
      password: password,
      server: srvaddress,
      options: {
        tdsVersion: srvaddress === 'gsoboss' ? '7_1' : '7_4'
      }
    });
    return pool;
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
};
```

and the `queryUnion` function:

```
const queryUnion = async (pool, query) => {
  try{
    let result = await pool.request().query(query);
    console.log(result);
    return result;
  }catch(err){
    console.error(err);
  }
}
```

the issue I'm running into is that the line in `remapGroups` that calls query union. it's running the query, but inside `queryUnion` it's never running the `return result` line.

The connection to the database is solid, and I can confirm that it works in other portions of code that do other things, and I have a feeling I'm misusing async/await in some way.

Comment: `forEach()` does not `await` the callback. Use a `for (const x of data) { ... }` loop instead of `data.forEach (async (x) { ... })`

Comment: that was it!!!!